# NestJS pipe stream to response

Tags: node.js, stream, nestjs

I'm learning about streams and trying a simple experiment. I want to pipe a readable stream into the HTTP response, but I get an error saying "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

What is the cause of this and how should I proceed ?

```
@Post('/pipe-into-response')
pipeIntoResponse(@Body() payload, @Res() response: Response) {
    const stream = new Readable();
    stream.on('end', () => response.end());
    stream.push('Hello World');
    stream.pipe(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already `stream.pipe(response)` you don't need to tell the response to `response.end()`. That should betaken care of by the `pipe` operation.